# Problem Related to Android Studio, Module version not found exception

Tags: java, android, dependencies, chrome-app-developer-tool

When  I try tot implementing this  ‘com.andrognito.patternlockview:patternlockview:1.0.0’ dependency it Shows could not found com.andrognito.patternlockview:patternlockview:1.0.0 Please can anyone help me to fix this error I want to create pattern lock view

I tried to import it and it can sync but when I try to run it it gives an error as I mentioned above

Comment: check missing repository for that dependency

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.